# Apache Superset installation issues

Tags: apache-superset

I have Ubuntu on a Windows machine and keep running into a few consistent errors:

1. One relating to the Werkzeug module: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'werkzeug.wrappers.etag'
2. A second related to a Flask environmental variable: You did not provide the "FLASK_APP" environment variable,
   How do I handle these? I'm not the only one hitting these issues e.g., https://issuemode.com/issues/apache/superset/105505036)

Answer (score -1):

2. try export FLASK_APP=superset
   this worked for me